# Multiple Database values in an php array

Tags: php

Suppose you have this:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $arr[] = $record['$columnvalue1'];
}
$arraycount = count($arr);
```

and you want multiple columns in the array how is this done?

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $arr[] = array($record['$columnvalue1'],$record['$columnvalue2']);
}
$arraycount = count($arr);
```

the above code errors:

```
Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!
```

Comment: why not just `$arr[] = $record`?

Comment: if you want multiple fields in array use like `$arr['field1'] = $record['field1']; $arr['field2']=$record['field2']` ..

Comment: I don't see an issue with your design, but I don't know what kind of data you're passing in, either.

Comment: You are leaving something out. The error is for a function not in your sample code.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Comment: `$arr[] = array($record['$columnvalue1'],$record['$columnvalue2']);
` is ok if you want just to keep two "columns" and not all the $record (which is an array too), and `count` would work

Comment: You can't use `mysql_fetch_assoc` on a query string, you have to use `mysql_query` first

Comment: You code snippet does not contain `array_count_values`, the warning message is generated elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple column values in to an array

```
$arr = array();
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($dbquery)) {
    array_push($arr,$record['$columnvalue1'],$record['$columnvalue2']);
}
```

To find the sum of the array

```
$arraycount = array_sum($arr); //to find the sum of the array
$num = sizeof($arr); //to find the size of the array
```